# Move multiple non-consecutive commits to different branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I've got two branches which shouldn't be directly merged together (yet). However, I need to move two different non-consecutive commits from one branch to the other. I currently have:

```
top-branch:
A-B-C-D

bottom-branch:
X-Y
```

And I want to get:

```
top-branch:
A-C

bottom-branch:
X-Y-B-D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you start from a situation similar to this one:

```
> git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate=short
* e08a53c (HEAD, bottom-branch) Y
* b659a43 X
| * 88612b2 (top-branch) D
| * 8b37e26 C
| * afe4ffd B
| * 5bc157c A
|/
* e3c7a2d other commit
```

I would start from branch `bottom-branch` cherry-picking the two commits you need

```
git cherry-pick afe4ffd
```

Then go back to `top-branch` and interactive rebase to remove the two commits you do not need

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wound up doing. I wasn't previously aware of `git cherry-pick`